# How could I fix it? Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setAdapter on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Want do some slides in my app.  In the activity the following code works fine, but in the fragments the app crashes and says something like:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)'
>   on a null object reference How can I fix this?

JAVA

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    sliderDotspanel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.SliderDots);

    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter); // HERE ERROR

    dotscount = viewPagerAdapter.getCount();
    dots = new ImageView[dotscount];

    for(int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++){

        dots[i] = new ImageView(this);
        dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.nonactive_dot));

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.setMargins(8, 0, 8, 0);

        sliderDotspanel.addView(dots[i], params);

    }
```

XML

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2" />
```

Comment: `viewPager` is null. Did you remember to call `setContentView()`? If so, did you do it _before_ the `findViewById()` calls? If yes, then it would seem that there is no `<ViewPager>` with ID `viewPager` in the currently loaded layout.

Comment: I'm new in this, could you explain how I do it?

Comment: How I can get in touch with you? Mike M.

Comment: I would like send image

Comment: Fix this issue please

Comment: It doesn't seem like images would help, in this case. It's purely a code issue. You need to call `setContentView()` with the appropriate `R.layout` before you make those `findViewById()` calls. If you've done that, then, as mentioned above, it would seem like your `ViewPager` is not in that layout.

Comment: Copy this project from another project that is working, but when migrating to my project this error appeared. My question is how can I solve if this is the same.

Comment: I can't give you any more specifics without seeing a [mcve]. At least, the code surrounding that posted, and the relevant layout XML file.

Comment: Can I add to my question code?

Comment: Go ahead Mike.........

Comment: Where is your `setContentView()` call? Which `R.layout` are you passing to it? Which layout file is that `<ViewPager>` in?

Comment: That error message is pointing to line 49 in the XML, not your code. We will need to see the complete stack trace; the whole section of red lines around that one.

Comment: Thanks! I got it!!